# links not accessible in xs screen size

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-5

I have a shopping cart with icons in the header that are links to login or display their cart.  They function on all size screens except phone (XS).  On a phone, they cannot be clicked or tapped.  same behaviour on a desktop with browser reduced to xs size.

```
        <section class="header-main">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row gy-3 align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-4">
                                <a href="Default.aspx" class="navbar-brand">
                                    <img id="imgLogo" class="logo" src="https://xxxx/Logo_200.png" style="height:40px;" />
                                </a>
                                <!-- brand end.// -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-lg-last col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-8">
                                <div class="float-end">

                                    <a href="Login.aspx" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Login/Logout/Register for an Account">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                                            <span id="lblSignIn">Sign In/Register</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    
                                    <a href="Wishlist.aspx" id="showWishList" class="btn btn-light position-relative">
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart">
                                            
                                        </i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline-block">My Wish List</span>
                                    </a>
                                    &nbsp;

                                    <a href="Cart.aspx" class="btn btn-light position-relative">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">
                                            <span id="MyCartBadge">
                                                <b class="notify">
                                                    <span id="lblNavCart">0</span>
                                                </b>
                                            </span>
                                        </i>
                                        <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline-block">My Cart 
                                        </span>
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- col end.// -->
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-12">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    
                                    <input name="ctl00$txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width:35%;" />
                                    
                                    <button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$btnSearch','')" id="btnSearch" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary vzindex"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- input-group end.// -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- col end.// -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- row end.// -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- container end.// -->
                </section>
                <!-- header-main end.// -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a meta tag in your html already for mobile compatibility? If not try using this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: yes i do have that meta tag

Comment: you can see the site here:  https://vistaweb.online